# Relationship between complex number and vectors

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers

What is the relation  between complex numbers and vectors?

I have read in some places "a complex number a 2-dimensional vector".

One can easily observe that $i\cdot i=-1$ in complex multiplication like the cross product of vectors.

Is  vector only the generalisation of complex number to n dimensions?

Is there any fundamental difference between those two?

Comment: If $z$ is a complex number, then $(Re(z),Im(z))$ is a vector in $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ is like the set of two dimensional real vectors $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the sense that you have a one-to-one mapping from the one into the other, except it has special rules for addition and multiplication, making it into a very special [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29).

Generalization to higher dimensions than 2 does not hold, except somehow for the case of the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions).

Addition is the same but multiplication is different. One way to look at complex multiplication is that it is like a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

There is a lot of ground to cover here, so I will give a reference. A very beautiful book that spends a lot of time on a detailed explanation and comparison of the two is Needham's "[Visual Complex Analysis](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//)". It is very difficult to match the explanations there in lucidity, pedagogy and geometric intuition. It is definitely one of the best mathematical prose I have read.

Comment: Regarding "Generalization to higher dimensions than 2 does not hold" — it *sort of* does, since you have quaternions, then octonions, following a 2^n pattern ([Cayley-Dickenson Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction)). As you gain dimensions, you lose some properties though, such as commutativity with quaternions.